# Dependant non-type template parameter and variadic template

Tags: c++, templates, template-specialization, c++14, indices

I am trying to extend the possibilities offered by [`std::integer_sequence`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/integer_sequence) with a new class named `integer_range` (which obiously creates a sequence of integers between two bounds). My implementation was based of my answer to [this question](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/45549/15094) that I tried to adapt to `std::integer_sequence`:

```
namespace details
{
    template<typename Int, Int C, Int P, Int... N>
    struct increasing_integer_range:
        increasing_integer_range<Int, C-1, P+1, N..., P>
    {};

    template<typename Int, Int C, Int P, Int... N>
    struct decreasing_integer_range:
        decreasing_integer_range<Int, C+1, P-1, N..., P>
    {};

    template<typename Int, Int P, Int... N>
    struct increasing_integer_range<Int, 0, P, N...>:
        std::integer_sequence<Int, N...>
    {};

    template<typename Int, Int P, Int... N>
    struct decreasing_integer_range<Int, 0, P, N...>:
        std::integer_sequence<Int, N...>
    {};
}

template<typename Int, Int S, Int E,  bool Increasing=(S<E)>
struct integer_range;

template<typename Int, Int S, Int E>
struct integer_range<Int, S, E, true>:
    details::increasing_integer_range<Int, std::integral_constant<Int, E-S>, S>
{};

template<typename Int, Int S, Int E>
struct integer_range<Int, S, E, false>:
    details::decreasing_integer_range<Int, std::integral_constant<Int, E-S>, S>
{};

template<std::size_t S, std::size_t E>
using index_range = integer_range<std::size_t, S, E>;
```

I thought that the change would be trivial (adding a `typename` template parameter), but this actually introduces a problem with a dependant non-type parameter in the specialization for `0`. Here is the compiler error:

```
error: type `Int` of template argument `0` depends on a template parameter
```

The basic problem [already has](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22486386/1364752) some solutions. However, since I use variadic templates, it becomes even harder to fix: [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22487113/1364752) can't work because I it is not allowed to have a default template parameter after a variadic template. Therefore, I tried to implement the fix mentioned in [the accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22486607/1364752) but it seems that, as mentioned in the comments, my compiler (g++ 4.8.1) is unable to disambiguate and considers that the two following specialization are both equally specialized:

- `struct increasing_integer_range<Int, std::integral_constant<Int, C>, P, N...>: /* */`
- `struct increasing_integer_range<Int, std::integral_constant<Int, 0>, P, N...>: /* */`

Is there any other way to fix this problem? I am out of ideas.

Comment: Does [this](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/353f112e2fce1593) not work with g++4.8.1?

Comment: If it doesn't you could try something like [this](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/392072523a4deac8) instead.

Comment: *"it is not allowed to have a default template parameter after a variadic template"* This is possible if you wrap the sequence and use partial specialization (e.g. pass the already constructed sequence as a `std::integer_sequence`).

Comment: @dyp If you instantiate it, the first one [does not work](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/95ddf9c45abd8f8d).

Comment: Ouch yes, I keep forgetting typedefs don't instantiate. The second one works, though (coliru uses a g++4.8.2).

Comment: @dyp That's some ugly hacks, but it works. Would you turn that into an answer? :)

Comment: There's a solution from 2012 [here](http://paulkeir.wordpress.com/2012/12/03/building-tuple-indices/) which also allows a non-unit stride.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would simply reduce your `integer_range` to a single, non-recursive call to `std::integer_sequence`:

```
namespace details
{
    template<typename Int, typename, Int S>
    struct increasing_integer_range;

    template<typename Int, Int... N, Int S>
    struct increasing_integer_range<Int, std::integer_sequence<Int, N...>, S>
        : std::integer_sequence<Int, N+S...>
    {};

    template<typename Int, typename, Int S>
    struct decreasing_integer_range;

    template<typename Int, Int... N, Int S>
    struct decreasing_integer_range<Int, std::integer_sequence<Int, N...>, S>
        : std::integer_sequence<Int, S-N...>
    {};
}

template<typename Int, Int S, Int E,  bool Increasing=(S<E)>
struct integer_range;

template<typename Int, Int S, Int E>
struct integer_range<Int, S, E, true>:
    details::increasing_integer_range<Int, std::make_integer_sequence<Int, E-S>, S>
{};

template<typename Int, Int S, Int E>
struct integer_range<Int, S, E, false>:
    details::decreasing_integer_range<Int, std::make_integer_sequence<Int, S-E>, S>
{};

template<std::size_t S, std::size_t E>
using index_range = integer_range<std::size_t, S, E>;
```

Which I tested with:

```
template<std::size_t... N>
void dummy( const std::integer_sequence< std::size_t, N... >& );

int main()
{
    dummy( index_range< 2, 5 >() );
    dummy( index_range< 5, 2 >() );
}
```

getting the expected linker errors:

```
main.cpp:(.text.startup+0xa): undefined reference to `void dummy<2ul, 3ul, 4ul>(detail::integer_sequence<unsigned long, 2ul, 3ul, 4ul> const&)'
main.cpp:(.text.startup+0x14): undefined reference to `void dummy<5ul, 4ul, 3ul>(detail::integer_sequence<unsigned long, 5ul, 4ul, 3ul> const&)'
```

[**Live example**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/7cfe4c1931161d3d) (with own implementation of `integer_sequence`, just skip the first part)

Comment: Hey! You're not Yakk.. ;)

Comment: That *does* seem to be a cleaner and less hackish solution :)

Comment: And as a result of my experiments with the above code (I screwed up while writing the live example by mixing up `index_sequence` and `integer_sequence`), I just submitted [Bugzilla #60942](http://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=60942) :)

Answer (score 3):

I'm just waiting for Yakk to suddenly appear out of nowhere and provide a non-hacky better solution ;) <sub>(I'm too tired to come up with something better..)</sub> but alas, this works for g++4.8.1:

```
#include <type_traits>

// C++1y Standard Library
// use this ONLY FOR TESTING PURPOSES
namespace std
{
    template<class T, T... vals> struct integer_sequence {};
}

namespace details
{
    template<typename T>
    struct minus_helper;
    template<typename T, T val>
    struct minus_helper< std::integral_constant<T, val> >
    {
        using type = std::integral_constant<T, val-1>;
    };

    template<typename T>
    using minus = typename minus_helper<T>::type;

    template<typename Int, typename C, Int P, Int... N>
    struct increasing_integer_range :
        increasing_integer_range<Int, minus<C>, P+1, N..., P>
    {};

    template<typename Int, Int P, Int... N>
    struct increasing_integer_range<Int, std::integral_constant<Int, 0>,
                                    P, N...>
        : std::integer_sequence<Int, N...>
    {};
}

template<typename Int, Int S, Int E,  bool Increasing=(S<E)>
struct integer_range;

template<typename Int, Int S, Int E>
struct integer_range<Int, S, E, true>:
    details::increasing_integer_range<Int, std::integral_constant<Int, E-S>, S>
{};

template<std::size_t S, std::size_t E>
using index_range = integer_range<std::size_t, S, E>;

int main()
{
    index_range<1, 5> f;
}
```

The reason why I think this could be done better is that *it seems* the increasing and decreasing range implementations are redundant. But I might have to consider corner cases (overflow) before providing a unifying solution.

For example, you can easily make a shifted integer range by using `std::make_integer_range` plus partial specialization plus pack expansion. But this might overflow.

Comment: If you think that it could be better, i will wait a little bit before accepting, but that's already good anyway :)

Comment: It'll not get any better today. Maybe tomorrow.

Answer (score 2):

> For example, you can easily make a shifted integer range by using
>   `std::make_integer_range` plus partial specialization plus pack
>   expansion.

A brief demonstration.

```
template<typename T>
constexpr T abs(T t)
{ return t < static_cast<T>(0) ? -t : t; }

template<typename Sequence>
struct match_sequence {};

template<typename Int, Int... Ns>
struct match_sequence<std::integer_sequence<Int, Ns...>> {
    template<Int Base, Int Stride = static_cast<Int>(1)>
    using Offset = std::integer_sequence<Int, Base + Stride * Ns...>;
};

template<typename Int, Int Low, Int High>
struct integer_range {
private:
    static constexpr auto width = abs(High - Low);
    using base = std::make_integer_sequence<Int, width>;
    static constexpr bool increasing = High > Low;
    static constexpr auto stride = increasing ? static_cast<Int>(1) : static_cast<Int>(-1);

public:
    using type = typename match_sequence<base>::template Offset<Low, stride>;
};
```

Comment: With that fix, [it compiles](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/bbf29b0e085ff367) (though my hacky `make_integer_sequence` is rejected by g++ for exactly the same issues Morwenn has in the OP - but that's not the issue here I guess).

Comment: That's interesting. But currently, it has one problem: `integer_range` does not inherit from/alias to `std::integer_sequence`. We only need one more alias template to solve the problem though.

Comment: @dyp By the way, compiler bug or not?