# Multiple parameter packs as factory function arguments

Tags: c++, templates, variadic-templates, parameter-pack

I am trying to create a factory method that instantiates a template class by passing the constructor arguments for the component classes as template parameter packs.

The `ProducerConsumer` template is parameterized on the types of the `Producer` and `Consumer`, which are aggregated by `ProducerConsumer`. Arguments to the factory function depend on the constructor arguments of the parameterizing classes.

I've studied [How can I have multiple parameter packs in a variadic template?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9831501/how-can-i-have-multiple-parameter-packs-in-a-variadic-template); the highest voted answer only counts the arguments in the parameter pack, it does not use them. I've also looked [Multiple parameter packs — how?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40052008/multiple-parameter-packs-how?noredirect=1&lq=1), which is rather uninformative for my problem as it passes a variable number of arguments of the same type.

What I have now generates errors at the `std::make_tuple` about not being able to cast to `tuple`'s private base class.

How do I forward a variable number and types of arguments to two different constructors within the factory function, `ProducerConsumer::create()`? Also, if and how should r-value reference be applied to the parameter packs being forwarded?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <tuple>
#include <chrono>


using Duration = std::chrono::steady_clock::duration;


struct ProducerBase {
    ProducerBase(Duration maxWait) 
        : maxWait_{ maxWait }
    {}
    Duration maxWait_;
};

struct ConsumerBase {
    ConsumerBase(int capacity, Duration maxWait) :
        capacity_{ capacity },
        maxWait_{ maxWait }
    {}
    int capacity_;
    Duration maxWait_;
};


template <typename Producer, typename Consumer>
struct ProducerConsumer {
    
    template < typename ... ProducerArgs, typename ... ConsumerArgs >
        static ProducerConsumer* create(
            std::tuple<ProducerArgs&& ...> producerArgs,
            std::tuple<ConsumerArgs&& ...> consumerArgs
        )
    {
        auto producer = new Producer(std::forward<ProducerArgs>(producerArgs)...);
        auto consumer = new Consumer(std::forward<ConsumerArgs>(consumerArgs)...);
        return new ProducerConsumer<Producer, Consumer>(producer, consumer);
    }

    ProducerConsumer(ProducerBase* producer, ConsumerBase* consumer)
        :
        producer_{ producer },
        consumer_{ consumer }
    {}

    ProducerBase* producer_;
    ConsumerBase* consumer_;
};

using namespace std::chrono_literals;

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    Duration const MaxWait{ 10s };
    int const Capacity{ 32 };
    using PC = ProducerConsumer<ProducerBase, ConsumerBase>;
    auto pc = PC::create(std::make_tuple(MaxWait), std::make_tuple(Capacity, MaxWait));
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two issues:

- forwarding reference is reserved to `T&&`, `C<T&&>` is not forwarding reference.
- tuple variable is not a variadic variable, you cannot use `...` on it. in C++17, there is [`std::make_from_tuple`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/make_from_tuple) to do what you want:

```
template < typename ... ProducerArgs, typename ... ConsumerArgs >
    static ProducerConsumer* create(
        std::tuple<ProducerArgs...> producerArgs,
        std::tuple<ConsumerArgs...> consumerArgs
    )
{
    auto producer = new Producer(std::make_from_tuple<Producer>(producerArgs));
    auto consumer = new Consumer(std::make_from_tuple<Consumer>(consumerArgs));
    return new ProducerConsumer<Producer, Consumer>(producer, consumer);
}
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/edcff941d294f825)

And as you don't use variadic, you might simplify it to

```
    template < typename ProducerTupleArgs, typename ConsumerTupleArgs >
        static ProducerConsumer* create(
            ProducerTupleArgs&& producerArgs,
            ConsumerTupleArgs&& consumerArgs
        )
    {
        auto producer = new Producer(std::make_from_tuple<Producer>(std::forward<ProducerTupleArgs>(producerArgs)));
        auto consumer = new Consumer(std::make_from_tuple<Consumer>(std::forward<ConsumerTupleArgs>(consumerArgs)));
        return new ProducerConsumer<Producer, Consumer>(producer, consumer);
    }
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/79bf2d674c49b7cf)

Comment: Works a treat! Thank you for the answer and for pointing me to make_from_tuple()!